# Cassandra error. Corrupt empty row found in unfiltered partition

Tags: cassandra

I am getting an error when I start a cassandra instance. Do you have any idea how I can fix it?

```
primecast-cassandra_1            | org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReadHandler$CommitLogReadException: Unexpected error deserializing mutation; saved to /tmp/mutation6385168154232968395dat.  This may be caused by replaying a mutation against a table with the same name but incompatible schema.  Exception follows: java.io.IOError: java.io.IOException: Corrupt empty row found in unfiltered partition
primecast-cassandra_1            |  at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReader.readMutation(CommitLogReader.java:410) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
primecast-cassandra_1            |  at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReader.readSection(CommitLogReader.java:343) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
primecast-cassandra_1            |  at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReader.readCommitLogSegment(CommitLogReader.java:202) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
primecast-cassandra_1            |  at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReader.readAllFiles(CommitLogReader.java:85) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
primecast-cassandra_1            |  at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.replayFiles(CommitLogReplayer.java:135) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
primecast-cassandra_1            |  at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recoverFiles(CommitLog.java:187) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
primecast-cassandra_1            |  at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recoverSegmentsOnDisk(CommitLog.java:167) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
primecast-cassandra_1            |  at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:323) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
primecast-cassandra_1            |  at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:601) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
primecast-cassandra_1            |  at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:730) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
```

Comment: It looks like, and hopefully, it's coming from the commit log. Any chance you can remove that commit log, let it continue and then run repair from other nodes (assuming you have other nodes in the cluster)? Or if the error is coming from some sstable, remove all the sstables for that table (along with their corresponding files) and run repair on that table to sync it up (assuming cassandra is down)?

Comment: Which version are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `nodetool describecluster`. It's likely you'll see more than one schema version. If you have more than one schema version:

1. Stop Cassandra
2. Delete the commitlog, and the saved caches (let me know if you need help with this)
3. Start Cassandra
4. Run `nodetool describecluster` to see if you just have one schema version now

Do the cleaning and restarting in all nodes in a rolling fashion.

Are you doing regular schema changes? If yes, it might be that the schema changes are not reaching all nodes quickly enough.

Answer (score -1):

interesting the nodetool drain is solving the issue. No idea how it works

nodetool drain

probably the memtable get flushed to sstable on this command

Comment: i am running cassandra 3.9,