# Cassandra error: Corrupt empty row found in unfiltered partition

Tags: java, cassandra

I have cassandra cluster with 3 nodes. After adding column to table I started seeing those errors in 2 of my cassandra nodes:

```
WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2022-08-08 10:34:29,219 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:169 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[SharedPool-Worker-1,5,main]: {}
java.io.IOError: java.io.IOException: Corrupt empty row found in unfiltered partition
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer$1.computeNext(UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.java:222) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer$1.computeNext(UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.java:210) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:47) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.PartitionUpdate$PartitionUpdateSerializer.deserialize30(PartitionUpdate.java:670) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.PartitionUpdate$PartitionUpdateSerializer.deserialize(PartitionUpdate.java:645) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.PartitionUpdate.fromBytes(PartitionUpdate.java:235) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.loadPaxosState(SystemKeyspace.java:1103) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.paxos.PaxosState.prepare(PaxosState.java:74) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.paxos.PrepareVerbHandler.doVerb(PrepareVerbHandler.java:33) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageDeliveryTask.run(MessageDeliveryTask.java:67) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:164) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$LocalSessionFutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:136) [apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:105) [apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_172]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Corrupt empty row found in unfiltered partition
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.deserialize(UnfilteredSerializer.java:368) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer$1.computeNext(UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.java:217) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
```

They appear when I make specific query in my application which throws this error:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_SERIAL (2 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException.copy(ReadTimeoutException.java:88)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException.copy(ReadTimeoutException.java:25)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:68)
    at com.twd.persistence.cassandra.BasicTable.getColumns(BasicTable.java:136)
    at com.twd.persistence.cassandra.BasicTable.getColumns(BasicTable.java:109)
    at com.tradeweb.tws.repository.impl.OrderServiceRepositoryImpl.getTrades(OrderServiceRepositoryImpl.java:80)
    at com.tradeweb.tws.service.impl.OrderServiceImpl.getTrades(OrderServiceImpl.java:124)
    at com.tradeweb.tws.web.controller.OrderResource.getOrders(OrderResource.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.tradeweb.tws.web.filter.TWDContentSecurityFilter.doFilter(TWDContentSecurityFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.tradeweb.tws.web.filter.TWDHttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(TWDHttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_SERIAL (2 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException.copy(ReadTimeoutException.java:115)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:124)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:473)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1070)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:993)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:323)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:648)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:583)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:462)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_SERIAL (2 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:62)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:289)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:269)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

I have run nodetool describecluster and it showed that schema on one of the nodes is unreachable. After that I restarted this node and describecluster showed that every schema is correct. This however did not stop those errors from showing. Since that I restarted every node like it is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59678908/9451651. I have also run nodetool repair -pr too on each node. Nothing helped and I am still seeing those errors. Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Update:
I found with nodetool scrub and sstablescrub commands that sstables for this table were broken. I truncated the table and repopulated it with the same data (I made backup with sql inserts). After running the inserts it threw an error that one row is corrupted. I removed this row and then repopulted the table again. This time no error. Now when I run nodetool scrub and sstablescrub it shows no issues with sstables however I am still seeing my original errors. I think that despite my sstables being correct right now the commit logs/caches are still broken. Do you know how I can fix that?

Update 2:
I resolved this issue by dropping the corrupted table and recreating it from backup we had before this issue started. Other fixes did not work in this case.